# My reputation has dropped 400 points all of a sudden. Can anyone tell me why?

Tags: support, reputation

Yesterday evening (GMT) my reputation dropped from 6650 to 6218 all of a sudden.  Why?

Comment: [Look here](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/61075/centaurus?tab=reputation) and it will tell you what happened.

Comment: It was probably a user whose account was deleted and who had voted for you many times.

Comment: related: [How do we get -840 reputation in a day?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3035/how-do-we-get-840-reputation-in-a-day); [Can I know which deleted user caused my loss of reputation?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4199/can-i-know-which-deleted-user-caused-my-loss-of-reputation); and [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted)

Comment: **and** [Did some of my answers recently get deleted?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1807/did-some-of-my-answers-recently-get-deleted/1811#1811)

Answer (score 6):

A couple of questions were deleted. I've undeleted them for the moment as there is nothing immediately obvious to indicate why they were deleted. If something is drawn to moderators’ attention, or otherwise comes to light, they may disappear again.

Those questions accounted for the majority of your loss, and you’re currently back to 6530.

We may be able to shed some light on what’s happened to the rest, but moderators don’t have access to a detailed history of reputation changes.